# Addition in SML using pattern matching

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm learning sml for the first time and I'm not too sure about the syntax for pattern matching.

As practice, I've tried to make some simple programs about binary numbers.

```
datatype Digit = Zero | One
type Nat = Digit list

fun inc [] = One::[]
| inc (Zero::rest) = (One::rest)
| inc (One::rest) = Zero::inc(rest)

fun dec [] = []
| dec (One::rest) = (Zero::rest)
| dec (Zero::rest) = One::dec(rest)


fun add (ds1, ds2) =
    let 
    fun addition ([],[],Zero) = []
            | addition (ds1, [], Zero) = ds1
            | addition ([], ds2, Zero) = ds2
            | addition (One, Zero, Zero) = (One::ds1)
            | addition (One, Zero, One) = Zero::addition(ds1,ds2,One)
            | addition (Zero, One, Zero) = (One::ds1)
            | addition (Zero, One, One) = Zero::addition(ds1,ds2,One)
            | addition (Zero, Zero, Zero) = (Zero::ds1)
            | addition (Zero, Zero, One) = (One::ds1)
            | addition (One, One, Zero) = Zero::addition(ds1,ds2,One)
            | addition (One, One, One) = One::addition(ds1,ds2,One)
    in
      addition(ds1, ds2, Zero)
    end
```

The first two work find but I can't get the addition to work. The point of the third function is to add binary numbers and return a list of the digits.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in `addition` is that `One` and `Zero` are not lists so they are incompatible with `[]`, `ds1` and the like.

You have done nicely with `inc` and `dec`. I think you can employ the same pattern for `add` and make use of `inc` which you have created:

```
fun add (ds1, []) = ds1
  | add ([], ds2) = ds2
  | add (Zero::ds1, d::ds2) = d::add(ds1, fs2)
  | add (One::ds1, Zero::ds2) = One::add(ds1,ds2)
  | add (One::ds1, One::ds2) = Zero::inc(add(ds1,ds2))
```

Comment: You can simplify that further: the first case is redundant, and similarly, the 4th to 6th case could be expressed by only two of the form `(Zero::ds1, d::ds2)` and `(d::ds1, Zero::ds2)`.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Thanks, I updated the answer based on your suggestion.